# Is it possible to fill out a document template via API and have the completed document sent to Carbon Copies without anyone needing to "sign" it?

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to programmatically fill all the fields of a template and send it to a user without requiring a person to "sign" it. Currently the best I've been able to do is have one signer (required for inserting fields) and a carbon copy user. But even if I submit all of the fields for the signer, they still have to open and review it before the document is completed and the CC is sent. I'm trying to avoid that extra review step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this with eSignature. Completed envelopes that were sent using eSignature requires a person to act on them, they cannot be fully automated.
You can use Digital Signatures with DSA to do that, but that's a completely different product and technology.

If you need to automate signing with eSignature, you can do that using Selenium web drivers for test automation.

Comment: There isn't actually a signature involved. I just need to automatically fill out forms and send them to people. I already have access to DocuSign and their API, so I was just hoping I could squeeze this functionality out of it so I wouldn't need to look into another tool. Thank you!

Comment: you can actually do this with DocuSign if you don't mind that the envelope is not "complete"
You do that by sending them to people using DocuSign, so this person is a recipient of the envelope. They will get an email from DocuSign and can see it. They won't get a filled PDF until they click "Complete" though...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can use **pre-fill** tabs and then just have cc recipients in the envelope. [Docs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/prefilled-tabs/)